# How to store different class objects in a single array/vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector, abstract-class

The program I'm writing requires me to implement a certain code so that every class instance that is stored in vectors is accessible within a single array or vector. The problem is that the instances belong to different classes and cannot be stored in a single array/vector by itself. Is there any way that this is possible? I implemented the code below, but unfortunately I got an error message which I couldn't seem to get rid of.

```
class A {...}; //abstract

class B : public A {...};
class C : public A {...};
class D : public A {...};
class E : public A {...};

vector <B> vecb;
vector <C> vecc;
vector <D> vecd;
vector <E> vece;
vector <A*> mainvec = { vecb, vecc, vecd, vece };
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with _Ty=A *, _Alloc=std::allocator<A *>]" matches the argument list
```

Comment: what kind of syntax is that one?? You have to put pointers to `A` in that `mainvec`, but you are trying to insert `vector`s

Comment: Try this:  `vector <A*> mainvec = {&vecb, &vecc, &vecd, &vece};`.  The `mainvec` wants pointers, not variables.

Comment: Visual  Studio Usage Note: Not far from the Error List tab you'll find the Output tab. The Output Tab contains the full build output in plain text. The Output tab is great because A) It's complete and may contain question-answering information that the executive summary in the Error List left out and B) text is dead easy to paste into a Stack overflow question and format.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `mainvec` wants pointers to classes derived from `A`, not pointers to vectors of classes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I still get the same error.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow arrays that hold objects of different types. So, basically, you're doomed. But what's the actual problem that you're trying to solve? There's probably a better way to go at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `vector <A*> mainvec = { vecb, vecc, vecd, vece };`

This can never work.  `mainvec` expects to hold raw `A*` pointers, but you are trying to pass it vectors of objects instead.

If you really want a vector to hold other types of vectors, you could use `std::variant` for that, eg:

```
std::vector<B> vecb;
std::vector<C> vecc;
std::vector<D> vecd;
std::vector<E> vece;

using VariantOfVectors = std::variant< std::vector<B>*, std::vector<C>*, std::vector<D>*, std::vector<E>* >;

std::vector<VariantOfVectors> mainvec = { &vecb, &vecc, &vecd, &vece };
```